# Python ttk notebook showing selected tab wrongly

Tags: python, tkinter, tabs, ttk

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class MainGame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)   
        self.parent = parent        
        self.initUI()

    def tab_change(self, event):
        tab_id = self.page.index('current')
        print(tab_id, self.page.tab(tab_id, 'text'))

    def initUI(self):
        global canvas
        self.parent.title('PythonPage')
        self.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = 1)
        self.page = ttk.Notebook(self, width = 646 ,height = 629)
        self.page1 = Frame(self)
        self.page2 = Frame(self)
        self.page.add(self.page1, text = 'Tab1')
        self.page.add(self.page2, text = 'Tab2')
        self.page.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', self.tab_change)
        self.page.pack(expand = 0, anchor = 'w', side = 'top')

root = Tk()
root.geometry('925x650')
main = MainGame(root)
root.mainloop()
```

`tab_change` can show their id and names, but not correctly.

When `Tab1` is clicked, I clicked `Tab2` but it still print `0 Tab1`, it needs one more click to print `1 Tab2` .

`Tab2` click to `Tab1` is the same, it needs one more click to show the current selected tab.

I want to find why the tabs need double click? And how can I get selected tab correctly by a single click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
self.page.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', self.tab_change)
```

To:

```
self.page.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.tab_change)
```

Because unless you have released the pressed button, the tab hasn't changed!

[image]